# Whats wrong with this expression?

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
Comments: Switch(((IIf(([qty_req]-[qty_on_hand])<0,0,([qty_req]-[qty_on_hand])))=0) And ((([qty_on_hand]-[qty_req])/[qty_req])<=0.2),"Please check manually")
```

I have been struggling with this expression for too long. I keep getting the error "This expression is typed incorrectly, or it is too complex to be evaluated. For example, a numeric expression may contain too many complicated elements. Try simplifying the expression by assigning parts of the expression to variables." I've tried breaking down the expression to see if there was a bracket I the wrong place but I can't figure this out.

Note: The word "Comments" is just the field name (I primarily use the Design View in MS Access).

**Update** - The goal behind this is to eventually add more conditions to this switch statement, but this first one isn't working so that's why it seems like it doesn't make sense to use a `Switch`. Also, in pseudo code, this is what the intention of this expression is:

```
Switch([TransferQTY]=0 And [Req is within 20% of Inventory], "Please check manually")
```

In regards to the first IIF statement:

```
IIf([Req-Inventory is negative, that means that we have enough on hand and don't need to send],0, [Req-Inventory])
```

Comment: your parentheses are out of balance (specifically the first `IIF` statement).  Also the `AND` does not make any sense where it is since it's not part of any logical expression.

Comment: can you tell us what this expression should do?

Comment: @CeOnSql I updated the question to clarify what it needs to do. @DStanley in regards to the `And` - I tried to surround the segment before and after in parentheses in order to make sure the `Switch` statement understands the separation - `Switch((A) And (B))`

Comment: @lurker Um it's MS Access 2007-2010 if that answers your question?

Comment: @lurker well....I am using Access as a front end. I like the Design view

Comment: Right, but using it's built-in database format - an `MDB` file - not an external SQL server (which is where I got snagged).

Answer (score 0):

The first IIF is just strangely built and has some redundancy to it. The second might give you strange answers because you don't have parans around your numerator. As it's written it could be simplified to:

As for the first `IIF`, you stated

> "IIf([Req-Inventory is negative, that means that we have enough on
>   hand and don't need to send],0, [Req-Inventory])"

in the context of the switch (psuedo-coded):

> Switch([TransferQTY]=0 And [Req is within 20% of Inventory], "Please
>   check manually")

This is basically saying "If the `quantity requested` minus the`quantity on hand` is less than or equal to 0", so instead of an IIF to do the "Less than or equal to" bit, just use `<=`:

```
Switch(((qty_req - qty_on_hand) <= 0) AND (((qty_on_hand - qty_req)/qty_req) <= 0.2), "Please Check Manually")
```

This will work better because Access is balking about the complexity. This dramatically reduces the complexity and accomplishes the same thing.

Also, I've gone a little heavy handed with the parantheses here. You could remove the ones that delineate each of the conditions that the `AND` function is evaluating and it would be fine.

---

I've removed the bit here about not using switch that was in a previous version of this answer since OP stated that `switch()` will be used after this bit starts working.

Comment: The first `IIf` definitely needs to be like that. It comes from another field in the same query `tqty: IIf(([qty_req]-[qty_on_hand])<0,0,([qty_req]-[qty_on_hand]))`. The thing is that I tried simply putting in [tqty] in the expression but I got some error about the expression not being part of an aggregate function....so I just put its definition in instead.

Comment: "If the quantity requested minus the quantity on hand is less than 0 then make this 0 else make this value the quantity requested minus the quantity on hand... now if that is 0 AND this other condition... then" You see how that can be simply reduced to say "If the quantity requested minus the quantity on hand is less than or equal to 0"... It's saying the same thing but without the redundancy.

Comment: Oh oh! I see now!! Thanks for simplifying that. Bad news though - I tried your code and I still get the same error....Update - I also tried removing the parentheses that you said it could do without and still nothing :/

Comment: Is `qty_req` or `qty_on_hand` being calculated upstream from this formula? Is this a query on top of a query? If the rabbit hole goes to deep, then access is going to choke like it is.

Comment: Actually yes, both of these values are calculations from another query that I am inner joined to.

Comment: That's probably the issue then. Consider making the underlying query a "Make Table" query and then query on top of that. Either that, or simplify the logic on the underlying query. Somewhere Access is getting choked up :/

Comment: Alrighty! Thanks a ton for your help! I sincerely appreciate it!!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's simply a check like this:

```
IIf([qty_req]-[qty_on_hand]<0 And ([qty_on_hand]-[qty_req])/[qty_req]<=0.2,"Please check manually","") AS Comments
```